# How can I remove esurf.biz malware from my browsers on windows 8?

Tags: malware

Since I can't add an answer to my last question about the esurf.biz malware (because busy body admins decided it was a duplicate of the question: "How do I remove malware in general"), I'm forced to post it again, so I can share my solution with people.

In short: how can I remove the awful crummy that is esurf.biz from my browsers?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is: reinstall your browser. I uninstalled firefox, then reinstalled it. Its magically gone. I suspect the malware infects the binaries of your browsers themselves. I haven't yet uninstalled chrome, but I will update this answer when I do. Internet explorer may be a more difficult fix, because if I remember correctly, you can't uninstall it.